# How to disable see elements trough transparent sticky-top menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I have a site with gradient background.
On this site I have sticky-top menu and under menu some content.
When I scroll down the content is visible trough menu. 
I don't want to set the same gradient as background have to navbar element beacause then is visible that difference between navbars and bodys background.

```css
body {
  background: transparent linear-gradient(123deg, #76FCFF 0%, #F966F8 52%, #E8BBA2 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0
}
.content {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px #38383880;
}
```

```html
<body>
<nav>Navbar content</nav>
<div class="content">
<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You can easily do this with javascript. You added the tag for javascript. Have you tried javascript?

Comment: I tried to get height of navbar and add it as padding top of body but it also moved down navbar. If it's so easily please write an answer with solution snippet @disinfor

Comment: That's not how this works. You should try a JS solution first - I looked at an answer you posted to another question which gave the impression you know JS - and then post if you get stuck. Here's a hint: think about adding a class on scroll so you can add a background to the `nav` and then removing the class once you scroll back to the top of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a problem using the same gradient.

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body, nav {
    background: transparent linear-gradient(123deg, #76FCFF 0%, #F966F8 52%, #E8BBA2 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

nav {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

.content {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    min-height: 120vh;
}
```

```html
<nav>Navbar content</nav>
<div class="content">
    <p>
    Content
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this. I don't know why this works in yours snippet but when I try this there is visible difference between bodys and navbars bg.

Comment: You'll need to create a demo that shows the issue. Here's a start: https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/dL08zapq/

Comment: I found out my problem. In my full code there is box shadow on content div.